# How to get the records for null value in the picklist field using dynamic soql

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, dynamic-soql

I have a picklist field Executed__c with None,Yes,No values in it.The query which i have written is fetching the records when the user selects yes or No.But when user selects None,null value is getting stored in the variable.But those records are not fetched Even though there are records for null value.How can i get those records?Please guide me.

Below is my apex class for that

```
    public class PrivateEquityReport
    {
      public Boolean isXLS {get;set;} 
      public List<Fund_Equity__c> activityRecords;
      public String displayPrivateEquity = '';

      ApexPages.StandardSetController regionStandardSetController{get;set;}

      public PrivateEquityReport()
     {
         activityRecords= new list<Fund_Equity__c>();
         regionStandardSetController=new ApexPages.StandardSetController(new  list<Fund_Equity__c>());
         String reportType =          System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('reportType');
         if(reportType=='XLS')
          isXLS = true;
         else
          isXLS = false;    

      }   

  String baseQuery  = 'SELECT '+''+'Id,Due_Date__c,Fund__r.Name,Company__r.Name,Subject__c,Comments__c,Date_Received__c,Business_Review__c,Attorney_Review__c '+''+'FROM Fund_Equity__c WHERE Team__c=\'Equity\' AND RecordType.Name=\'Amendment\'';

  public String getReportText()
 { 

     system.debug('*************'+isXLS);

     String checkQuery = baseQuery;

     String executedCheck=System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('Executed');
     System.debug('*******executed check******'+executedCheck);
     String reportFromDateVar= System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('dFromDate');
     Date fromDateVar = null;
     if(reportFromDateVar != null)
     fromDateVar = Date.valueOf(reportFromDateVar);
      System.debug('*****From Date***'+fromDateVar );

     String reportToDateVar  =System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('dToDate');
     Date toDateVar = null;
     if(reportToDateVar != null)
     toDateVar = Date.valueOf(reportToDateVar );
     System.debug('*****To Date***'+toDateVar );

     String reportReceiveFromDateVar= System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('rFromDate');
     Date receivefromDateVar = null;
     if( reportReceiveFromDateVar != null)
     receivefromDateVar = Date.valueOf( reportReceiveFromDateVar);
     System.debug('*****Receive From Date***'+receivefromDateVar );

     String  reportReceiveToDateVar = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('rToDate');
      Date receivetoDateVar = null;
      if( reportReceiveToDateVar != null)
      receivetoDateVar = Date.valueOf( reportReceiveToDateVar );
      System.debug('****Receive To Date***'+receivetoDateVar );


      if((fromDateVar!= null)&&(toDateVar!=null))
     {
      checkQuery =checkQuery  +' '+'and (Due_Date__c>=:fromDateVar AND Due_Date__c<= :toDateVar )';
      system.debug('************3'+checkQuery  );
     }

     if((receivefromDateVar != null)&&(receivetoDateVar !=null))
     {
      checkQuery  =checkQuery+' '+'and (Date_Received__c>=:receivefromDateVar AND Date_Received__c<= :receivetoDateVar )';
      system.debug('************3'+checkQuery  );
     }

    checkQuery=checkQuery +' '+' and Executed__c=:executedCheck';
    system.debug('************3'+checkQuery);
     regionStandardSetController=new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(checkQuery));

     activityRecords= regionStandardSetController.getRecords();
     system.debug(activityRecords);
     system.debug(activityRecords.size());
   // System.debug('*****records*****'+activityRecords);

     if(isXLS)
    {
     displayPrivateEquity ='<table><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>' + displayPrivateEquity ;                
     displayPrivateEquity =    prepareReportSinglePagePrivateEquity(activityRecords,displayPrivateEquity );
    }
    else
    {

     displayPrivateEquity  = prepareReportSinglePagePrivateEquity(activityRecords,displayPrivateEquity );
     displayPrivateEquity +='<DIV style="page-break-after:always"></div>';  
    }     
      return  displayPrivateEquity;
}

  Public String prepareReportSinglePagePrivateEquity(List<Fund_Equity__c>     fundListVar, String reportString)
 {


   reportString+='<table width="100%" table-layout:"fixed" style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 12px" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">';
   reportString+='<THEAD>';
   reportString+='<tr align="left" style="background-color:#C0C0C0; color: ;"><th width="5%">'+'Due Date</th>'+'<th>'+'Fund</th>'
          +'<th width="5%">'+'Company</th>'+'<th width="5%">'+'Subject</th>'
          +'<th>'+'Comments</th>'+'<th>'+'Date Received</th>'
          +'<th>'+'Business Review </th>'+'<th width="5%">'+'Attorney Review</th></tr>';

   reportString+='</THEAD>';       

 }    

}
```

I am taking params value from another controller as below

```
 public PageReference viewReport() 
{

    String params = '';
    if(dueFrom.Due_Date__c!= null)
    params+= '&dFromDate='+String.valueOf(dueFrom.Due_Date__c);

   if(dueTo.Due_Date__c!= null)
    params+= '&dToDate='+String.valueOf(dueTo.Due_Date__c);

   if(receivedFrom.Date_Received__c!= null)
    params+= '&rFromDate='+String.valueOf(receivedFrom.Date_Received__c);

   if(receivedTo.Date_Received__c!= null)
    params+= '&rToDate='+String.valueOf(receivedTo.Date_Received__c);

   params+= '&reportType='+reportType;

   params+= '&Executed='+fundActivityObj.Executed__c;
   System.debug('**********Executed******'+params);


   if(params.startsWith('&'))
   params = params.substring(1);
   System.debug('*****Final*****'+params);

   PageReference pageRef = null;    
   if(reportType=='PDF')
        pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/EquityTrackingPDF?'+params);
    else if(reportType=='XLS')
        pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/EquityTrackingXLS?'+params);
  pageRef.setRedirect(false);  

return pageRef;

}
```

VF Page

```
<apex:page sidebar="true" showHeader="true"  controller="PrivateEquityCriteria" tabStyle="Fund_Activity__c">

<apex:sectionHeader title=" Tracking report"     subtitle="Criteria"/>
 <apex:panelGrid id="test">
    <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages> 
 </apex:panelGrid> 
   <apex:form > 
      <apex:pageBlock title="Funds">
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="AI Private Equity Weekly Legal Tracking" columns="2" >
      <apex:inputField label="Executed" value=" {!fundActivityObj.Executed__c}"/>
      <apex:inputCheckbox label="Due Date" value="{!dueCheckBox}" selected="true"/> 

     <apex:inputField label="Due Date From" value="{!dueFrom.Due_Date__c}"/>
     <apex:inputField label="Due Date To" value="{!dueTo.Due_Date__c}"/>
     <apex:inputField label="Due Received From" value="{!receivedFrom.Date_Received__c}"/>
     <apex:inputField label="Due Received To" value="{!receivedTo.Date_Received__c}"/>

    <apex:selectList id="reportTypeId" value="{!reportType}" size="1" label="Report Type" > 
   <apex:selectOption itemValue="PDF" itemLabel="PDF"/>
   <apex:selectOption itemValue="XLS" itemLabel="XLS"/>
  </apex:selectList>
 </apex:pageBlockSection>

   <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
    <apex:commandButton value="Run Report" action="{!viewReport}"/> 
   </apex:pageBlockButtons>

 </apex:pageBlock>
```

Thanks.

Comment: `executedCheck` flag is populated from URI params as per your code. Can you confirm it holds correct value when you select `None`? Better you post the required sections of page source as well.

Comment: Hi can you please update this line **checkQuery=checkQuery +' '+' and Executed__c=:executedCheck';** to  **checkQuery=checkQuery +' and Executed__c=: ' + executedCheck;** you have taken that variable inside the string

Comment: @highfive,Yeah you are right i am taking the executedCheck from URI Params ,i have updated that part above please refer.

Comment: @Nilesh if i change as you said i am getting the error in the page "Only variable references are allowed in dynamic SOQL/SOSL ".

Comment: try adding this line and see String executedCheck= (System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('Executed') != null && System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('Executed') != '') ? String executedCheck=System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('Executed') : null;

Comment: @Shailesh thanks for the reply...if i change the executedCheck i am getting Error: Compile Error: expecting a colon, found 'executedCheck . What i have to change?

Comment: There was a mistake in adding the comment: it should be  
String executedCheck= (System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('Executed') != null && System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('Executed') != '') ? System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('Executed') : null;

Comment: @Shailesh i am getting "Only variable references are allowed in dynamic SOQL/SOSL" error in the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your viewReport() method where you're doing

```
params+= '&Executed='+fundActivityObj.Executed__c;
```

null gets converted to 'null'
you can check this in sample

```
String var = null; 
String var2 = ''+null; 
System.assertEquals(null, var); 
System.assertEquals('null', var2);
```

So, 
1. 
If you want null then change your code in viewReport() method as

```
if(null != fundActivityObj.Executed__c)
   params+= '&Executed='+fundActivityObj.Executed__c;
```

So you don't have a request param itself and you get null in getReportText().

or else

2.
Step 1:
change your code in viewReport()

```
   params+= '&Executed='+(null == fundActivityObj.Executed__c)?'':fundActivityObj.Executed__c;
```

And
Step 2:
Here in

```
String executedCheck=System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('Executed');
```

you will get '' as value for executedCheck and it is not null.

So modify in getReportText()

```
executedCheck = (null == executedCheck || '' == executedCheck )?null:executedCheck ;
```

Comment: if i change the code as you said...i am getting "Only variable references are allowed in dynamic SOQL/SOSL " error in the visualforce page.Please suggest.

Comment: did you check System.assertEquals(null, executedCheck); ?

Comment: I checked that i am getting "Assertion Failed: Expected: null, Actual: null error in the page if i add system.assertEquals

Comment: can you check this System.assertEquals('null', executedCheck); ? you might be getting string as 'null'

Comment: yeah i checked with System.assertEquals.....if i add that i will get the error in the page as Assertion Failed: Expected: null, Actual: null

Comment: yes I know. But you can try that for testing what you have received. And tell me which one is giving you error,  System.assertEquals(null, executedCheck);  or  System.assertEquals('null', executedCheck);  or System.assertEquals('', executedCheck);  Try one each time.

Comment: ok @Saumya i will try it and let you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36217/discussion-between-learner-sfdc-and-saumya-ranjan-satapathy).

Comment: Thanks a lot saumya for your time :) the first way which you suggested worked for me 
if(null != fundActivityObj.Executed__c) 
params+= '&Executed='+fundActivityObj.Executed__c; 
This one worked.Can you please explain what this if(null != fundActivityObj.Executed__c) line is checking....As we usually do if(fundActivityObj.Executed__c != null).What is the difference between them?

Comment: That is just a style. It is like keeping expected first and actual second the way it is in 'system.assertEquals(expected, actual)'.

Comment: And it is the null check that solved your problem, not this style. You can write it as 'fundActivityObj.Executed__c != null'.